# css line-height : number to px

Tags: javascript, html, css

am doing an automation tool which has to pick html css properties (font-color, size, etc..), and am done most of the part.Here the problem is, some case am getting the css property(line-height), **line-height : 1.54** . Here for some purpose, i need to convert the number(1.54) to px value(like, line-height : 15px). So, Is it possible to do this calculation ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can you please, let me know how to calculate this one?

Comment: Looks like hsz has already a good answer to _that_ question.

Comment: You can also use the dev tools. Look for `line-height` under the 'computed' tab - it will show a value in pixels

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Unitless `line-height` refers to the `font-size` of the element.

If your element has set `font-size: 14px`, do the simple math:

```
1.54 * 14px = 21.56px
```

You can get more information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height